# Add extra processing via annotations

Tags: java, spring, printing, annotations, runtime

I'm making a small project and I'm currently stuck on a way to achieve one of the capabilities I need.

Basically I want a method to execute when I'm calling an annotated method.For example

```
@PrintAnnotation
public void print(){
  System.out.println("inside method");
```

The print annotation would just print extra test, so on calling the above method I would like to get

```
"Used print annotation"
"Inside method"
```

That's all.

I'm looking into the annotation processor API but there is no documentation anywhere except reading the javadoc which is crazy, and if I understand correctly its compile only so you cant change the original classes, only add.

I also found answers suggesting to use reflection, but to use reflection I need code triggered that checks if the method is annotated, but to do that I have to add an extra method to every method in the program, like

```
public void print(){
   checkAnnotation();
   System.out.println("test");
}
```

But I need it to work with only adding the annotation, not hundreds of one lines in every method of every class.

Comment: Look into AOP...

Comment: I don't think this is possible without using an AOP library or calling the method explicitly through reflection and inserting the print statement there.

Comment: Why exactly would you need this, and especially without using a readymade tool for the job?

Comment: well it's basic plugin functionality.I dont really want to just print a line, ill insert some processing there, but i figured it would be easier for stackoverflow to answer that as a simpler example.About the tool, well i dont like dependencies.That tool must do it with java somehow.Maybe at worst case i will study it

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible through "only annotation" with no third party libraries and no custom code.

Annotation is only an annotation and nothing else.

It means you have to have those `print` and `checkAnnotation` methods which will detect presence of your `Annotation` on desired Target (Class,Method, Field...) and do what you'd like to. `System.out.println("test");` definitely will not do that.

If you go with those `print` and `checkAnnotation` methods - create an utility with those methods and call `print` from anywhere instead of `System.out.println`.

But actually, what you try to achieve is about AOP. Your custom annotation can be used with it.

Then, you tagged question with `spring` tag, do you use Spring? It is a set of third party libraries and has AOP.

Comment: I realize the annotation is only a marker.And i got the basics of reflection down just fine, but im stuck in a different part.

I want to do something like

     `for each class`

    `   for each method`
   `       if method = annotated`
    `         on method.call = doPrint()`

But java doesnt have events so im kinda puzzled

Comment: You have to check AOP. `for each class ... for each method...` is a really very bad idea :-). Still, what about to pass caller's `Class` or `Method` as parameter to `Print`/`checkAnnotation` methods to analyze presence of annotation?

Comment: If this is a school assignment then I think you can create a proxy factory using reflection. I think this is what the assignment would call for if your constraints must hold. Then you would not call "new" but make calls to your static proxy factory passing in the type you want constructed. If this isn't a school assignment then this would be silly, especially if you're using spring already.

Comment: You would be looking to manually implement your own run time weaving(spring), as opposed to compile time weaving (aspectj).

Comment: This is not for a school assignment, my uni didnt even teach java lol, i want to make a plugin that will add additional capabilities to servlet.But to apply it to microservices i want it to be able to be usable even in plain tomcat and not contribute to large unviable fat jar sizes.So it has to be small and simple without extra libraries.Just one annotation and boom your servlet does thing X